# List of emails clients which MAPISendMail can work

Tags: c#, mapi, mapisendmail

Can someone give me a list of Client email programs which MAPI (MAPISendMail function) can be used on. I know I can use MAPI functionality in OUTLOOK, however I need to know does it support other emails clients like Thunderbird or Lotusnotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your asking the wrong question, MAPI is windows API so any windows client program should be able to use the api

Messaging Application Programming Interface (MAPI) is a messaging architecture and a Component Object Model based API for Microsoft Windows. MAPI allows client programs to become (e-mail) messaging-enabled, -aware, or -based by calling MAPI subsystem routines that interface with certain messaging servers.

The full Extended MAPI interface is required for interfacing messaging-based services to client applications such as Outlook. For example, several non-Microsoft e-mail server product vendors created "MAPI service providers" to allow their products to be accessed via Outlook. Notable examples include Axigen Mail Server, Kerio Connect, Scalix, Zimbra, HP OpenMail, IBM Lotus Notes, Zarafa, and Bynari.

MAPI also had a service provider interface of sorts. Microsoft used this to interface MS Mail to an email system based on Xenix, for internal use.

Extended MAPI is the main e-mail data access method used by Outlook, to interface to Microsoft Exchange, via MAPI service providers shipped with Outlook.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messaging_Application_Programming_Interface